# Prove that if $f \in \mathcal L^1(\mathbb R)$ then $fx^n \in \mathcal S'(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

On my notes I found an  unproven statement:

"If $f \in \mathcal L^1(\mathbb R)$ then $fx^n \in \mathcal S'(\mathbb{R})$"

Why is it so? I know that $\mathcal S(\mathbb{R})$ is contained in  $\mathcal L^1(\mathbb{R})$, here it seems to suggest the opposite. Then a continuous functional on $\mathcal S(\mathbb{R})$ would of course be a tempered distribution...

Comment: If $g\in S$ then $x^ng$ is bounded.

Comment: @zhw but here I have $g \in L$ which means that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| dx <\infty$$

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: Note that it says $\mathcal{S}'$, not just $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Yes I noticed it, but if f was in S it would be proven: $$|fx^n \le C \int_{\mathbb{R}} dx(1+|x|^n)|f(x)|| \le C \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2} dx \le K \sup_x(1+x^2+|x|^n+|x|^{n+2})|f(x)| \le K(||f||_{0,0}+||f||_{2,0}+||f||_{n,0}+||f||_{n+2,0}) $$ @md2perpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove that $fx^n$ (assuming $n\geq 0$) is a tempered distribution, that is, the functional
\begin{align*}\mathcal{S}&\to \mathbb{R}\\ 
g&\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} fx^n g
\end{align*}
is continuous. 
By Holder's inequality, and since $g\in \mathcal{S}\Rightarrow x^ng\in \mathcal{S}\subset L^{\infty}$,
 $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)x^n g(x)|dx\leq \|f\|_{L^1}\|x^n g\|_{L^\infty}<\infty$$
Moreover, the following implications hold:
$$g_k\to^{\mathcal{S}} 0\Rightarrow x^ng_k\to^{\mathcal{S}}0 \Rightarrow \|x^ng_k\|_{L^{\infty}}\to 0 $$
Thus if $g_k\to^{\mathcal{S}} 0$ then by the previous inequality $\int_{\mathbb{R}}fx^ng_k \to 0$, and the functional is continuous.

Comment: Grazie @Lorenzo, I you made me everything clear!